# How to know when one view is on top of another view based on co ordinates of that view in android

Tags: android, kotlin

**What I am trying to do:**

- I have a `textView` which I am dragging on the screen.
- I have a `button` at a certain position of screen which does not move
- I want to find out when the textView comes on top of button

**What I have done:**

- I have the coordinates of textView when it gets dragged
  **`textYcoordinate`** and **`textYcoordinate`**
- I have the static location of button **`buttonXcoordinate`** and
  **`buttonYcoordinate`**

**Code I have**

```
override fun onTextInputDragged(text: String, x: Float, y: Float) {

        Log.d("","")
        val ksarLocation = IntArray(2)
        binding.tvKsar.getLocationOnScreen(ksarLocation)

        var buttonXcoordinate =ksarLocation[0]
        var buttonYcoordinate =ksarLocation[1]

        var textXcoordinate = x
        var textYcoordinate = y


 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to know the button size as well. You can construct a `Rect` of each View and use the `intersects` function.

I haven't tested this, so sorry for any errors in the details:

```
val View.screenRect: Rect 
    get() = locationOnScreen.let { (x, y) -> Rect(x, y, x + width, y + height) }

fun View.intersects(other: View): Boolean = Rect.intersects(screenRect, other.screenRect)
```

But it seems maybe you haven't moved the TextView yet in this listener, so you could create a rectangle using the new position and test it against the `screenRect` (as defined above) of the button.

```
val textViewRect = with (binding.myTextView) { Rect(x, y, x + width, y + height) }
val overlapsButton = Rect.intersects(textViewRect, binding.tvKsar.screenRect)
```